# How do I use the shell method to calculate the volume of this region between two solids of revolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, 3d, volume, solid-of-revolution

My question is how do I calculate the volume of the region between $f(x) = (2x+1)\sqrt{x^2 + x}\,$, $\,g(x) = x^2\,$, and $x = 1$ using the Shell Method?

Here are the 3D visuals I graphed using [Geogebra.](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/bwrgpaxu)

[image]

[image]

I've already solved it using the Disc/Washer Method:

$$ I_\text{Disc/Washer} = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \pi \left[\left((2x + 1)\sqrt{x^2 + x}\right)^2 - \left(x^2\right)^2\right] \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{143\pi}{30} $$

I think the answer is already correct but I still would want to be able to solve it using the Shell Method, too, if possible. Here's what I've tried so far by using [an inverse branch of $\,(2x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x}\,$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+%282x%2B1%29+%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2Bx%7D).

$$ I_\text{Shell} = \int_{y=0}^{y=3\sqrt{2}} 2\pi y\left[\sqrt{y} - \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{16x^{2}+1}+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \,\mathrm{d}y $$

The result is $\,\dfrac{\pi}{30}\left(432\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt{3}-391\right)\,$ [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B3%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D+2%5Cpi+y+%28%5Csqrt%7By%7D+-+%28-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B%5Csqrt%7B16y%5E2%2B1%7D%2B1%7D%2F%282%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%29%29%29+dy) which doesn't seem to match up with $\,I_\text{Disc/Washer}\,$ but I don't know where I made a mistake. Did I get the lower and upper limits wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the last integral into two regions. The integrand has your form up to $y=1$. Above that value, the length of the shell is bounded by $x=1$, not by $x=\sqrt y$.

$$ I_\text{Shell} = \int_{y=0}^{y=1} 2\pi y\left[\sqrt{y} - \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{16x^{2}+1}+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \,\mathrm{d}y +\int_{y=1}^{y=3\sqrt{2}} 2\pi y\left[1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{16x^{2}+1}+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \,\mathrm{d}y$$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much! I kept thinking on how to split the Integral into two parts but I couldn't figure it out on my own. Once again, thanks for your help, I really appreciate it, have a nice day :)